# Spring BootにおけるJUnitがUnresolvedになる。

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

## Spring BootにおけるJUnitがUnresolvedになる。

### 概要

現在、Kotlin + SpringBootを参考書を使用して入門中です。
そこで、参考書通りにJUnitを使用したテストコードを書き、`% gradle test`を実行したところ下記のようなエラーが発生しました。ライブラリが正常にインポートされていないのは理解できています…。

自分なりに色々調べてみましたが解決せず…。

どなたか解決方法のご教授お願いいたします。

### エラー内容

```
> Task :compileTestKotlin FAILED
e: /Users/kondohiroki/IdeaProjects/demo_db/src/test/kotlin/com/example/hello_db_app/demo_db/ControllerTests.kt: (6, 18): Unresolved reference: Before
e: /Users/kondohiroki/IdeaProjects/demo_db/src/test/kotlin/com/example/hello_db_app/demo_db/ControllerTests.kt: (7, 18): Unresolved reference: Test
e: /Users/kondohiroki/IdeaProjects/demo_db/src/test/kotlin/com/example/hello_db_app/demo_db/ControllerTests.kt: (8, 30): Unresolved reference: Before
e: /Users/kondohiroki/IdeaProjects/demo_db/src/test/kotlin/com/example/hello_db_app/demo_db/ControllerTests.kt: (10, 18): Unresolved reference: runner
e: /Users/kondohiroki/IdeaProjects/demo_db/src/test/kotlin/com/example/hello_db_app/demo_db/ControllerTests.kt: (21, 2): Unresolved reference: RunWith
e: /Users/kondohiroki/IdeaProjects/demo_db/src/test/kotlin/com/example/hello_db_app/demo_db/ControllerTests.kt: (30, 6): Unresolved reference: BeforeEach
```

### 該当のソースコード

```
// ControllerTests.kt

package com.example.hello_db_app.demo_db.controllers

import com.example.hello_db_app.demo_db.MainController
import com.example.hello_db_app.demo_db.User
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Before
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
class ControllerTests {

　　　　テスト処理...略

}
```

```
// build.gradle.kts

import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.2.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.61"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.61"
}

group = "com.example.hello_db_app"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Before
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
```

同名のクラスをimportし過ぎですね。例えば、以下のようにどれか1つにして下さい。

```
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
```

それから、`build.gradle.kts`を見ると、（`'junit-vintage-engine'`）をexclude（除外）しているので、JUnit 5ベースのテストケースは正常に動作しますが、JUnit 4ベースのテストケースは動作しないようです。

```
testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
    exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
}
```

一方、テストクラスのアノテーションはJUnit 4のもののようです。

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
```

これから新規にアプリケーションを作成するのであれば、どちらかのバージョンに統一した方がいいと思います。

参考書を見ながら入門中ということのようですので、その参考書と同じバージョンを使用した方が無難かもしれません。

参考：
https://www.javacodemonk.com/migrating-spring-boot-tests-from-junit-4-to-junit-5-00aa2839